# How to make the variable calcuate immediately while running npm run build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I defined a variable in index.js file.

```js
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: isDev ? '/site-map' : '/single-order',
  },
  isDev && {
    path: '/site-map',
    name: 'site-map',
    meta: { title: '页面导航' + isDev, keepAlive: true },
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "site-map" */ '../views/site-map/index'),
  }]
```

I noticed that this variable was not calculated when packaging, but turned it into a variable, which led to some of the useless code is packaged into the result file.

[image]

But if I use the defination directly, The useless code will not be include into result file.

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '/site-map' : '/single-order',
  },
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && {
    path: '/site-map',
    name: 'site-map',
    meta: { title: '页面导航', keepAlive: true },
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "site-map" */ '../views/site-map/index'),
  }]
```

This turn to

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/single-order',
  }]
```

Did anyone know how to fix this, that is make the variable calcuate immediately while npm run build, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your bundler assumes that the `isDev` variable is a specific to your code and not a development code.

Just use `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable directly without passing it to a variable.